# how to set cub out effect in viewpager with different fragmaents / layouts

Tags: animation, android-viewpager, effect

my viewpager is different (with multy xml and java file.means page1 java and xml file,page2 java and xml file,page3 java and xml files are seprate).
and want to sate **cubeout** effect in my viewpager.

**this is my coad **

public class MercuryActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnPageListener {
    List fragments = new Vector();
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page1Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page2Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page3Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Page4Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragments);
    this.mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

}



public void onPage1(String s) {
    ((Page2Fragment) this.fragments.get(1)).getView();
    ((Page3Fragment) this.fragments.get(2)).getView();
    ((Page4Fragment) this.fragments.get(3)).getView();

}


public void onBackPressed() {
    new Builder(this).setIcon(17301543).setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MercuryActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            MercuryActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```

}
}

**and this is my page adapter**

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List fragments;

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (Fragment) this.fragments.get(position);
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}